# Advertencia : argumento no válido proporcionado para foreach ()

Tags: php

Hola estoy tomando datos desde una api y al momento de pasarla por un foreach(), me imprime una advertencia de argumento no valido

```
   echo "<table id='tabla' class='display tabla' style='width:100%'>
   <thead>
  <tr>
      <th>ID del Ticket</th>
      <th>Asunto</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>";
  $data = json_decode($response);
  foreach($data as $tkt){
      echo "<tbody>";
     
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $tkt['id'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $tkt['subject'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      echo "</tbody>";
  
    }
  echo "</table>";

}´´´
```

Comment: Puede ser porque foreach espera un arreglo, al momentor de codificarlo en json pierde por decirlo así ese formato de array

Comment: Has un ```var_dump($data);```,  a ver si te imprime un array en pantalla, caso contrario ya sabes el error.

Comment: Comprueba que los datos te están llegando como esperas, imprime la variable `$data` y asegúrate de que recibes un array. Para imprimir el error pon `die(var_dump($data));` si no activa los errores de php con estas lineas:     `error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Answer (score 0):

**El problema es el siguiente:**

Al momento de utilizar la funcion  `$data = json_decode($response);`  esto se transforma en un `objeto` de tipo `stdClass`  y no un array.

Para acceder a sus valores en el `foreach`  tendrías que hacerlo de la siguiente manera   `$tkt->id`

O en su lugar convertir la respuesta a array a asociativo  `$data = json_decode($response,true);` y entonces si podrias utilizar `$tkt['id']`

[Documentacion](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php)